# How to tell when an instance of Command Prompt is closed, in java?

Tags: java, batch-file

I've had a bit of an issue, and I'm pretty new at Java. For context, I'm making a GUI in Javafx, with a Batch backend. The GUI only has to call the Batch script(core.bat) once, and know when it has ended after it has been called. Currently, I call the Batch script using the following code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c start core.bat");
} catch(IOException ioException) {}
```

The issue comes into play when I need to know when the Batch script has ended. I would give examples of what I've tried so far, but I've tried so many things over the past three hours and overwritten my code so many times that I just don't know anymore.

Any solution will do. I just need some way to determine when the Batch script has ended, after which it will close itself. Due to this, knowing when the Batch script ends is not the only possible method. 
Knowing when the instance of command prompt running the script ends is also an option.
Any solutions are helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Process#waitFor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--). It waits until the process has finished.

You might need to start a new Thread if you don't want to wait for it but only get notified/execute code when the program is finished(blocking seems not like a good idea in JavaFX):

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    Process p1 = runtime.exec("core.bat");
    Thread t=new Thread(()->{
        try{
            p1.waitFor();
            //your code
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            Thread.currentThread.interrupt();//not actually needed, but I think it is a good practise and...SonarLint :)
        }
    });
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
} catch(IOException ioException) {}
```

Also, you executed the cmd command `start`, that starts a new process that you cannot control that easily. Just execute `core.bat` or `cmd /c core.bat`

`setDaemon(true);` marks your Thread as a daemon Thread, that does not affect the end of the Program(ends if all Threads that are no daemon Threads finished).

Comment: Now I remember, that was one of the solutions I used. The issue was that it seemed to be waiting for the end of starting core.bat, not the actual command prompt instance created. As when I generated an infinite batch loop, used waitFor, and returned an exit value, it returned immediately. Didn't try setting it as a Daemon though, so I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: If you need `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr`, you can use `Process#getXXXStream()`.

Comment: waitFor() generated a try-catch error, possibly due to erroneous code or a difference in JDK/Java version, I'm not sure. Either way, I added the Try-catch statement and made this:

Comment: Right. I wrote it on my mobile phone and didn't think of that. Edited again

Comment: I'm also new to stack overflow, and it doesn't seem like there's a way to put code in comments. However, I tested out your solution. It didn't seem to work, as I added a println statement, and it did not execute after the waitFor() method when I closed cmd.

Comment: @JustinVogel you can put code in comments with `\`` before and after the code. But you can not put line breaks here.

Comment: The cmd window is another process. You might be able to access it via child processes or just not open a new window and get the i/o by the `getXXXStream` methods of `Process`.

Comment: If my answer helped you, I would appreciate you accepting it.